# Swift 2, how to get values from multistage JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to get values from a multistage JSON response.
For my login I get the following JSON data from my server:

```
{
"status": "...",
"payloadList": [
    {
    "type": "...",
    "authToken": "...",
    "user": {
        "id": ...,
        "firstName": "...",
        ...
        }
    }
]
}
```

to get the value firstName I tried the following:

```
do {
  let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]

  if let payload = (json["payloadList"] as? [AnyObject]){              
     NSLog("Payload: %@", payload);
  }
  } catch let error as NSError {
     print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Since it's multistage, I convert it into string: anyobject and not dictionary.
The payload looks now like this:

```
payload:  (
    {
    authToken = ...;
    type = ...;
    user =         {
        id = ...;
        firstName = ...;
        ...
        };
    }
    )
```

To get the first name I should now go through the anyobject. 
Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
if let user = (payload["user"] as? [AnyObject]){              
 NSLog("user: %@", user);
}
```

does someone know how to get the firstname out of it by go through the anyobject or does someone have an other solution from scratch by not using anyobject?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use SwiftyJson .

Comment: `payloadList` is an array of dictionaries (`[[String:AnyObject]]`), `user` is a key of `payloadList` and a dictionary (`[String:AnyObject]`)

Answer (score 0):

Your payload is an array of AnyObject objects. So you have to access to its objects by index. Try this variant:

```
for payloadItem in payload {
    if let user = payloadItem["user"] {              
        print("user: %@", user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

user is not an array but dictionary. Try the following, it should work:

```
if let user = (payload["user"] as? [String:AnyObject]) {
    print("\(user)")
}
```

Comment: Any explanation for the down vote please? Try implementing this and you will see that it will work. payloadList is an Array thats why `as? [AnyObject]` works; however, for the user is not an array but a dictionary, which you need to test `as? [String:AnyObject]`.

Comment: it wasn't me, I didn't try your answer because the first one worked for me. But thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, anyway. You should select the correct answer though if it worked for you.

Comment: You can't get "user" property of an array. It will crash because array doesn't have such property.

Comment: No it won't crash. I use it like this all the time. Also, FYI, NSLog DOES work in Swift.

Comment: @oyalhi NSLog returns error 'NSLog' is unavailable: Variadic function is unavailable at least in XCode 7.3 playground. Accessing to the array by "user" key also returns error Cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject] with an index of type String. And that fact that you use it like all the time doesn't actually mean that it would work in this particular situation.

Comment: Did you import UIKit? or Cocoa? You need to import these to make NSLog work. Also please don't waste anymore of my time. Whatever you say is true and I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @oyalhi Yes, I imported UIKit. And there is no such module as Cocoa. I've tried Foundation but it didn't work anyway. I'm here not only to teach somebody, but to teach myself as well. So help me to understand your point and you'll also learn something new.

Comment: I am uploading a video to youtube where you can see the playground and the NSLog works. Also uploading another video with a very simple xcode project with swift and nslog and shows that it's working. Just importing the UIKit will suffice. If it's not working that means you are doing something wrong. Please check the videos and let's talk afterwards. Video1: https://youtu.be/vQTFcIgzhcU  Video:2 https://youtu.be/SbesKc9ATR8. They are processing so it may take couple of minutes for you to see.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it does work in such case. It will return an error if you try to print user description using NSLog("user: %@", user) if user is AnyObject. Casting user to some type will fix the error though. Thank you for clarifying this for me! And I would really appreciate if you can also record a video with accessing user object by key without a crash.

Comment: In your example you are casting it to AnyObject; however, actually it is [String:AnyObject] so you can safely try that. I have done another recording directly from the project that I am developing, I put 2 break points to the json parser one with short json output and one with long json output. I clear the debug window each time. Here is the link: https://youtu.be/YtD4jLIPic0 which should be ready in couple of minutes.

Comment: @oyalhi Again, you're absolutely right that user is a dictionary so it can be easily converted to [String:AnyObject] and be used as you described. And thanks once more for recording a video. This helped me to understand that we're talking about different things a bit. I meant that payload var that you're using in your example is representing payloadList array from income json, not a dictionary. So accessing to its objects by key "user" might bring a crash. If you use some kind of iteration through its objects than it would be definitely correct.